# how to convert array which is a dictionary objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

my array

```
{
    cash = 860;
    flat = 157;
    propertyName = "Four seasons";
},
    {
    cash = 540;
    flat = 156;
    propertyName = "Four seasons";
},
    {
    cash = 560;
    flat = 155;
    propertyName = "Four seasons";
}
```

how to convert array which is a dictionary with the same strings in another array with the dictionary

```
{
    cash1 = 860;
    cash2 = 540;
    cash3 = 560;
    flat1 = 157;
    flat2 = 156;
    flat3 = 155;
    propertyName = "Four seasons";
}, ...
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: All the dictionaries in the array have the same keys?

Comment: yes have 4 keys

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary *finalDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [arrayOfDict count]; i ++){NSDictionary *subDict = arrayOfDict[i]; for (NSString *aKey in subDict){[finalDict setObject:subDict[aKey] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%ld", aKey, i+1]];}}`?

Answer (score -1):

This might help you out.

FYI this is much simpler...

```
   NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   for (NSDictionary *dict in yourArray)
 {
    [result addEntriesFromDictionary:dict];
 }
```

Comment: If all the dictionaries have the same key, you'll have only the last dictionary. Because there is unicity if the key in a dictionary.